# How to re-design my current SQL Case Logic implementation in Teradata 13.0

Tags: sql, database-design, case, teradata

I am building out a Staging layer for Master Data and have the following situation and current solution. My Transaction data has nothing but Master Data id's or "codes" and no text descriptions. Most all my text descriptions are delivered in a single generic table which has all the possible "codes" and their subsequent text values. In moving this data into the Staging layer I need to trim the codes from the VARCHAR(60) into their actual field length based on their original field length.

in short, Master Data codes are moved from the source environment where they are correctly cast into this Landing environmental and a VARCHAR(60) where they get padded. I need to trim according to field length as I move into Staging.

I am using the following SQL, but have wrapped it in CASE logic to manage the different possible field lengths I will see. I have to therefore reproduce this bit of logic for each different MD code I deal with. I am looking for a way to tweak this so that it handles all field lengths in one bit of logic.

```
SELECT ATTR_NM
    , CASE 
        WHEN ATTR_NM = 'DOC_TYP'
            THEN(
                CASE WHEN CHARACTER_LENGTH (TRIM(BOTH FROM tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD)) > 1
                    THEN SUBSTRING( tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD FROM CHARACTER_LENGTH(TRIM(BOTH FROM tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD))-1)
                    ELSE tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD
                END
                )
    WHEN SAP_ATTR_NM = 'ACCT_GRP'
        THEN(
            CASE WHEN CHARACTER_LENGTH (TRIM(BOTH FROM tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD)) > 4
                THEN SUBSTRING( tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD FROM CHARACTER_LENGTH(TRIM(BOTH FROM tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD))-2)
                ELSE tx.MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD
            END
            )
        END AS MSTR_DATA_ATTR_CD
    , LANG_ISO_CD AS LANG_ISO_CODE
    , tx.LANG AS LANG
    , tx.END_DT AS END_DT
    , tx.FRM_DT AS FRM_DT
FROM MASTER_DATA_DESC_BASE_VOL tx;
```

I can't just Trim leading 0's since I can have a code with a leading 0. I need to know the field length and then apply that numeric value with the Trim function call. Or someone has a better way altogether. I am a longtime programmer consultant, but somewhat new to Teradata.

Also, this is working and currently handles more than 20 different cases and runs rather efficiently. I just know there is a better way to do what I need and I will also have to continue to add more and more Cases.

Comment: Do you have multiple MSTR_DAA_ATTR_CD values that could be the same length? To improve the performance of the CASE logic you can place the most frequently occurring conditions at the top to eliminate the processing of the case logic as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Yes out of the possible 50 or so total MD Code types, they could be categorized into about 5 - 6 Case statements and that is the way I would go if I could not shake it all the way down to one statement. I am thinking that all the field metadata I need will be in DBC.Columns or close by. If in my Case statement I had the field name, which is in ATTR_NM I could grab the necessary field length and ....... somehow use it within my logic. Its just getting to be ugly SQL as it stands.